# Problem with getting a JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is my code that sends a form via AJAX and then is meant to display a message back to the user

```
var postValues =   {
                name: $($nameObject).val(), 
                email: $($emailObject).val(),
                message: $($messageObject).val(),
                form: $(this).find('input[name=form]').val()
            };


            var form = this;


            $.post(config.basePath + 'contact/', postValues, function(data) {

                // get json here and make sure it sent



                 console.log('done request!');

                console.log(data.success);

                var $statusObject = $(form).find('.status-message');


                if (data.success) {

                    console.log(data.message);

                    $statusObject.removeClass('failed').text(data.message);

                    setTimeout(function() {

                        $statusObject.fadeOut(1500).remove();

                        $(form).find('input[type=text], textarea').val('');

                        $(form).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled').parent('div').removeClass('sending');


                    }, 1500);

                } else { // error with ajax

                    $statusObject.addClass('failed').text(data.message);
                    $(form).find('button[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled');

                }




              }, 'json');



            return false;


        });
```

Firebug says that the JSON being returned is

> {"success":true,"messsage":"Sent
>   successfully"}

I can easily get the value of `data.success`, but whenever I try and access `data.message` it is set to 'undefined'.

However, when I do

`console.log(data)`

I get the correct output into Firebug:

> Object success=true messsage=Sent successfully

What sounds like the cause of this? It's driving me a bit insane!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your return string in Firebug is me**sss**age... notice the extra s.

I think that might be your problem ;)

Comment: I'm giving you the accepted answer because you have the least rep :)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access `data.message`, but your JSON has `data.messsage`.  With three esses.

Comment: Wow! I knew it had to be something stupid like that. Thanks chaos :)